# Installing graphviz in Windows10 64bit

Tags: python-3.x, windows, graphviz, neato, anaconda3

I've installed graphviz, following the command given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202558/8281509), to use it with Networkx

```
conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz
```

But there is a problem while trying to run the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587921/8281509)

```
raise ValueError("Program %s not found in path." % prog)
ValueError: Program neato not found in path
```

I searched a bit and found [Neato missin](https://github.com/mahkoCosmo/GraphViz_x64/issues/2)g for 64 bit version.

Does this problem still exist? Is there a way to install Neato?

EDIT:
Following the instructions given below, I have installed Graphviz in the following folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38
```

Could someone suggest how to proceed from here?

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
```

doesn't work.

So I tried,

```
pip install pygraphviz
```

returns

```
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2987): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
    Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
```

I'm not sure how to install pygraphviz now.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that **neato** is missing.

As per your post seems like your system does not know where neato is. So add the directory where `neato.exe` is contained in to your PATH environment variable.

On Windows10, this can be done with `Start -> Edit environment variables for your account -> select path in the window -> edit -> New -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\`

or whatever your install directory is.

Comment: Thanks for the reposne. I don't find the bin folder. C:\xxx\xxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.41-0\ contains include, info, Library, Scripts, share

Comment: @Natasha Please download the stable version here it is the link:- https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html Please just let me know if any confusion over there.

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know how to uninstall  graphviz installed using `conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz`

Comment: If you are using windows then just go to Control panel and uninstall that program simple :)

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find in the control panel

Comment: So please download the stable version and repair with the existing one if ask

Comment: I downloaded the stable version and installed and added the path in environment variables. But I am not sure how to import the package now. `import pygraphviz as pgv` says cannot find the package. I could find neato in bin now.