# Installing pygraphviz in Windows10 64 bit

Tags: windows, networkx, python-3.7, pygraphviz

I've installed pygraphviz using

```
conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz
```

But there was a problem since neato was missing, so I uninstalled the above and did the following.

From the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600549/installing-graphviz-in-windows10-64bit/60600671?noredirect=1#comment107213227_60600671) I downloaded graphviz [msi](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html) and installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38` and also installed.

Could someone suggest how to proceed from here?

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
```

doesn't work.

So I tried,

```
pip install pygraphviz
```

this returns

```
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2987): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
    Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
```

I'm not sure how to install pygraphviz now.